# I tried the Hash Tables: Ransom Note problems but obtained conflicting results in some tests

Tags: python, function, dictionary, if-statement

I applied an `if` statement in the function, but it returned conflicting results.

The function is to match words with magazines. It returns both 'Yes' and 'No' after an `if` statement. Can anyone take a look what I have done wrong?

The test inputs are:

```
magazine=['give', 'me', 'one', 'grand', 'today', 'night']
note=['give', 'one', 'grand', 'today']
```

```py
import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys
from collections import Counter

# Complete the checkMagazine function below.
def checkMagazine(magazine, note):
    m=Counter(magazine)
    d=Counter(note)
    match=False
    newdict = {k: m[k] for k in d}
    if newdict.items()>=d.items():
        match=True
    if match:
        print("Yes")
    print("No")
```

No errors, it just doesn't match the answers. The answer should be "Yes", but my function returns both "Yes" and "No".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should place `print('No')` under a condition.

```
def checkMagazine(magazine, note):
    m=Counter(magazine)
    d=Counter(note)
    match=False
    newdict = {k: m[k] for k in d}
    if newdict.items()>=d.items():
        match=True
    if match:
        print("Yes")
    if match==False:
        print("No")
```

Comment: Your code looks clearer, however still shows an issue at the test. for inputs magazine=['two', 'times', 'three', 'is', 'not', 'four'], note=['two', 'times', 'two', 'is', 'four']. The expected outcome is No, but the code returns Yes. I tried put 'print("No") under a condition before posting the question, it returned an error saying the position of 'print' was wrong.

Comment: I am thinking the problem here is the values in the magazine are sometimes larger than its matched values in the note, and the positions of the keys in the two lists/dictionaries are different. I tried comparing the values and the key positions, but still returns errors in some tests.

Comment: Tried: print('Yes' if all(k in d.items() for k in newdict.items()) else 'No'), got 5 failed tests out of 20.

Comment: @SHendricks I wrongly assumed that you were checking whether `magazine` contains all the elements in `note`.

Comment: You assumed right. The shortcode works ok for some tests. The updated answer produced the same outcome that has 5 out of 22 failed tests. I just cant see anything wrong with the code. There are other solutions online but none of them worked out all the tests.

Comment: @ ComplicatedPhenomenon The problem is unsolved, but thanks for your effort.